# Is a set of one element is the same as an element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to figure out how sets work.

I do understand that {∅} ≠ {{∅},∅}.
just as {1} ≠ {{1},1}.
But does 1 = {1} ?

Comment: No, these are not the same objects. $1$ is a **number** while $\{1\}$ is a **set** that contains the number $1$.

Comment: No!  Don't do it!  Think of the children!  ... look.  It's simple that sets are different things than the elements inside the sets.  No-one gets those confused for large sets.  Yet people get confused with some sets are want to make exceptions for {} and {{}} or 1 and {1} because these exceptions ... well, I guess in they don't distinguish they don't get confused.  But these inconsistencies will just cause everything to fall apart and nothing will work and nothing will make sense.  Don't do it.  Just don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If $\{1\} = 1$, then since sets don't have repeated elements, we would have:
$$
\{\{1\}, 1\} = \{1, 1\} = \{1\}
$$
which contradicts what you already know.

Answer (score 1):

The proof he gave proves it. But there's a simpler way to think about it.

The difference is subtle. Think about the difference between a set and an atom.

A set is a collection; An atom is something that's not a set.*

1 is an atom
{1} is a collection with a single atom as its member.

Is a collection an atom? 
No.
Then 1 and {1} are not identical, that is 1$\neq${1}.

*Note that a set can be thought of as an atom, of course. For instance {1,2}$\neq${{1,2}}.b Atom is more of a contextual term. You're thinking of a set as an atom when you're not thinking of its *set properties*, but rather only as some object that's in a collection.

What I gave you is an intuitive argument; it should settle your confusion. In all of this logical stuff you're learning right now, don't lose sight of your intuition. It would have kept you from stumbling over this. Proofs like above are important for checking your intuition. You need to be good at both.